# jQuery - display div fro

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, show-hide

I am creating a members' profile page. The members' names are links to their bio's id. The desired outcome is that when each person's name is clicked, their bio details appear in a specific css-styled box on the page. The box's background and border are visible when the page loads, but no content. When another name is clicked, the previous bio returns to hide and the current one changes to show. There is probably a simple answer to this that this newbie just doesn't get.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#bioLinks div a").click(function(){  
                $("#bios .show").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
                var bio = $("#bios ." + $(this).attr("id"));
                bio.removeClass("hide");
                bio.addClass("show");
                })
        });
</script>
```

The css for the styled portions of the links and box:

```
#bios {background:#FFFFCC; border-style:solid; border-color:#ffd119; padding:15px; width:600px;text-align:left;position:absolute; top:200px;left:20px;}
.show {display:block; width:600px;}
.hide {display:none;}
.biopic {float:left; margin-right:15px; width:200px; height:200px; border-style:solid; border-color:#000099;clear:left;}
.biostext {display:inline; margin-left:15px; font-family:Georgia, serif; clear:right;}
#bioLinks {float:left; display:block; font-family:Georgia, serif;  margin-left:25px; margin-top:15px;clear:right;}
a {font-family:Georgia,serif; color:#0000ff; text-decoration:none;}
```

The links themselves, although in reality there will be dozens:

```
<div id="bioLinks">
  <div><a href id="bio1">Joe Bloggs</a></div>
  <div><a href id="bio2">Monica Faux</a></div>
  <div><a href id="bio3">John Doe</a></div>
</div>
```

And the bios themselves, but with the photos expunged for privacy:

```
<div id="bios">
        <div class="bio1 hide">
            <!--div class="biopic"><img src="http://www. -- snip--.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Joe Bloggs"-->
            <!--/div-->
            <div class="biostext">Joe Bloggs is just like everybody else.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bio2 hide">
            <!--div class="biopic"><img src="http://www. -- snip--.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Monica Faux"-->
            <!--/div-->
            <div class="biostext">Monica Faux is a belle with a shady past.</div>
         </div>
         <div class="bio3 hide">
            <!--div class="biopic"><img src="http://www. -- snip--.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="John Doe"-->
            <!--/div-->
            <div class="biostext">John Doe is an unknown in the organisation.
            </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

When I test my code in Chrome and IE, the empty box displays on load, but clicking the links produces nothing.

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle? Also - in your example all the HTML is commented out. Was that a mistake?

Comment: Not sure about how to create a jsfiddle? All of the html is not mean tot commented out, only the img src divs?

Comment: The W3 Schools validator is trying to be helpful, but I'm too ignorant to know what this means: Error Line 85, Column 16: "HREF" is not a member of a group specified for any attribute
  <div><a href id="bio1">Joe Bloggs</a></div>

Comment: I'm still stumped as to why the same code is working in these fiddles and not on a page. I've tried stripping back a page to just this code as it appears in the fiddles, and it won't work that way either.  In IE, the links don't even appear as links, the cursor stays as an I-bar.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJK7k/)

I believe your problem is syntactical. You shouldnt be double binding `$(document).ready()` and it looks like there is one less than the required amount of closing brackets in any case.

Change your javascript to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bioLinks div a").click(function () {
        $("#bios .show").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
        var bio = $("#bios ." + $(this).attr("id"));
        bio.removeClass("hide");
        bio.addClass("show");
    })
});
```

And see if that fixes the problem

On another note, you used the incorrect method of commenting out HTML. The closing comment of HTML is `-->` not `--!>`

Comment: Whoops, thanks for that clarification on commenting out, and I'll try your changes when I get back to the system with the file on it.  You're right, it looks like a cut'n'paste error from my working file.

Comment: Alas, still nothing.  But neither solution works on my page, so I suspect the error is elsewhere.  Thank you for the fresh pair of eyes, though!

Comment: See my answer to Sheikh Heera above, if I'm correct that the fiddle is marking erroneous code in red, why are dmany of my css attributes so marked? They can't be fatal errors if your demos work even with the red code?

Comment: Not sure why the CSS values are being highlighted. They may not adher to the W3 standards even though the browsers can parse them. fixing the problem with your markup is important since some browsers will handle missing close tags and attributes differently than others

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$("#bioLinks div a").click(function () {
    $("#bios > div").removeClass("hide").hide();
    var bio = $("#bios ." + $(this).attr("id"));
    bio.show();
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qJK7k/1/)

Comment: This looks interesting, and I can't try it out right now, but would this still work for users clicking around non-sequentially?

Comment: YES, IT DOES, CHECK THE DEMO.

Comment: Hmm, it works really well on the demo, but not at all on my page, so I guess the script is not the problem.  Thank you, though, an answer that raises more questions is still an answer.

Comment: I edited this to get rid of the extraneous (p) in the bio texts, a relic of a previous attempt.  That cleared up my red-marked div ends in the fiddle.  I haven't worked with this (brilliantly handy btw) fiddle before, but it looks like it's marked erroneous code in red.  So why are the fiddle demos flagging my href id="bio1" etc as red? Several of my css attributes are also marked in red, but I don't see anything worng with them?

Comment: I've twigged in that I was referencing jQuery 1.something-ancient, and have updated to use 1.9.1 as you've used in the fiddle, but without success.

Comment: Now, what is the problem ?